How to aggregate the uncertainty around many predictions?
I have predicted trends for hundreds of time series. Each trend prediction comes with its own upper and lower bound at each time step. I would like to aggregate these trends and report them. Taking the mean of the predictions is straightforward for aggregating the trends themselves, and mean works perfectly in my case. However, I am unsure how to appropriately aggregate the upper and lower bounds for the mean prediction.
Simply taking the mean of the bounds might not be accurate. Another option is to take the range (e.g., the maximum of the upper bounds and the minimum of the lower bounds), but this could result in unrealistically high uncertainties. This is because the variance among time series might be high, even though the uncertainty of individual trend estimates is low, and the range would reflect the overall uncertainty without accounting for this variation.
Could someone please explain a mathematically sound approach to aggregate the uncertainty for these predictions?

To answer that 'mathematically sound', please add what kind of uncertainty the lower and upper bounds of your prediction do encode.

Thanks. I am using the Rbeast trend analyses. According to the original manuscript, the upper/lower bounds are the credible 95% confidence interval. Its a Bayesian averaging model that fits many linear models. Here is the link to the original paper: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MFZ0FpK1NwTieVSAf5jicLgl85Lm48uh/view
